# No login screen after boot even though password set for user

Tags: linux, login, lubuntu

When I installed it, I set up using with password option, so it never had the password from beginning, but now I can't enable it.

I've three users that are present in system:

[image: My users in system]

For akshatk i've set password using the command:

```
sudo passwd
```

When i try to become superuser, it asks for `[sudo] password for akshatk:`

However, when I boot up my system it shows a gray screen instead of login one for split seconds. After that it automatically shows my desktop without asking for
password or anything.

How do I set password access for my system?

I use Lubuntu 20.04 (a derivative of debian and ubuntu with lxqt running).

Please guide me if I need to mention some other details and such.
I also once change the system name directly from the `/etc/hostname` could that have anything to do with this?

Comment: You need to disable auto login for that user. Open Settings app, go to Users section, unlock as admin, disable auto-login for the user in question.   https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-automatic-logon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, it seems autologin was indeed on and i just couldn't figure out where to switch it off from.

There is file /etc/sddm.conf where you can basically delete the autologin function.